# Is there an original etymology for "Xenomorph" outside of the origin in the movies?

Tags: etymology

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22134/what-is-the-etymology-of-xenomorph-in-the-context-of-the-aliens-franchise) on a different SE site asks the question of what the etymology of the word "Xenomorph" is, and the consensus, from the comments at least, is that it has none - that it was purely invented for that movie.

My question is, is this true?  Did this word purely exist as a creation of the movies, as a portmanteau of two separate words?  Or is there an origint that dates back to before the creation of these movies?

I realize this is the ELU stack exchange, so I don't expect a detailed explanation of the etymological origins movie-side, I'm simply curious if there is any evidence that this word existed prior to the Alien franchise.

Comment: It's put together out of two common Greek words: ξένος, _xénos,_ 'stranger; foreign'; and μορφή _morphé_ 'shape, appearance'. So it means 'strange shape' and that means it looks like an alien. Anybody can do this with Greek roots; Lego is coming out with a new set.

Comment: *"**Entymological** origins"*? These would be those xenophobically stereotypical aliens that evolved from insects, I take it. (So technologically advanced they use Leg6, rather than Leg0 to coin new words :)

Comment: The word exist since the XIXth century...but in German, in the field of geoglogy. And under the form xemorphae in English, in entomology.http://books.google.ca/books?id=qW9TAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA35&dq=Xenomorphae&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=hpWIU47bJ8WQyAT0oYDQAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Xenomorphae&f=false

Comment: @Jo: oic. So OP's *Entymological* wasn't necessarily a typo then? (But it's still a misspelling, whichever way it goes).

Comment: @ fumblefingers He made a lucky portmanteau

Comment: Fact is, I caught the typo in the two other places I used the word in my question before posting it, but not that last one.  Fixed.  Obviously I'm not implying an insect-origin for the Xenomorphs.

Comment: [The Moving Finger writes; and, having writ, 
Moves on: nor all thy Piety nor Wit 
Shall lure it back to cancel half a Line, 
Nor all thy Tears wash out a Word of it.](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/365850.html) So I shan't remove my comments even though the original inspiration is gone. As a matter of fact though, aliens are very often portrayed as insect-like. But when did you last see a movie where the aliens looked like *elephants*, say? Or *kangaroos?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Lord of the Rings and Tank Girl. (/Joke answer)

Comment: Actually, I think I shot myself in the foot there! I seem to recall one of the *Star Wars* movies has some kind of attack vehicles that look like giant mechanical elephants. And the eponymous stars of both *Alien* and *Predator* bound around rather like kangaroos. They've thought of everything.

Comment: @JohnLawler : would that be a new Lego λέγω set?

Comment: @BrianDonovan: I believe it's called the _Ablaut_ set; comes in three grades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word existed, and exists, with a different meaning in geology, in which it refers to crystals trapped between other rocks and crystals (I may have the geological details of that not quite right). It is used in such works as  Edward Huntington Williams' *Manual of Lithology: Treating of the Principles of the Science with Special Reference to Megascopic Analysis ...* from 1895, which considerably predates the *Alien* franchise.

In both this case and the films, the etymology is from the establish process of combining Latin and/or Greek words (in this case both Greek) and so *ξένος* (stranger, foreign, alien) and *μορφή* (shape, form, body).

It applies in the geological sense, because such crystals are foreign bodies within another rock.

It applies in the film because such creatures are alien/foreign to all organisms otherwise known to the protagonists.

(Incidentally, as used in the film it does *not* refer specifically to the eponymous aliens; it refers to any real or hypothetical non-terrestrial being. If, on their way to LV-426, the crew of the USS Sulaco came across a being that looked like a lovable turd, asked to "phone home" and healed people with a glowing finger while saying "ouch", they would have called that a *xenomorph* too [and then cut him up to see if his finger was of use to medical research]).

Both the Greek words involved have a history of being used in English, such as *xenophobe* and *xenoblast* for *ξένος* and *endomorph* and *lagomorph* for *μορφή*. This last example compares well, as it is similarly used to describe creatues (it covers both rabbits and hares, and literally means "having the form of a hare").

As such, it would be a pretty unsurprising coinage for a scientist to make, whether a real 19th century scientist looking at crystals in rocks, or a fictional 22nd century scientist describing an extra-terrestrial species.

Comment: [Here's](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The+xenomorph+says%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) a usage from 1979 that seems to be pretty much OP's "sci-fi" meaning: *"The **xenomorph** says they have adopted human form to avoid frightening Earthlings with their appearance".*

Comment: @FumbleFingers good find. Not at all surprising given how obvious the coinage is (though not the only such possibility), but I failed to find one such myself in a quick search.

Comment: Presumably because as @Jo comments above, the word seems to have a long history in *German* texts. I don't know why Google Books have so many obviously foreign texts filed under "English", but it does rather complicate searching sometimes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers and in terms of timing, it's worth noting that while the first *Alien* film was in 1979 too, that film didn't use the term *xenomorph*, though the 1986 sequel did.

Comment: @FumbleFingers for a term based on Greek from 19th century geology, that is not a surprise: Geology was *the* gentleman's science of the time in both Britain and Germany (France to a lesser degree) and since part of the point of coining such terms from classical roots is to allow for valid use in other European languages, its something you're likely to find with geology and other sciences popular at the time. Why Google mis-categorises them when it generally does well in this regard is another question. Perhaps for once it over-depended on metadata, and that metadata was flawed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That sounds like a pretty good answer in itself.  Especially if you can back any other previous references to it in literature.

Comment: It wouldn't demonstrate that the word wasn't (re-)coined for the films though. The practice of combining classical words in such a manner being so common, it's pretty likely to have been independently created for the film.

Comment: Right. It isn't like words are always created once and then exist forever. Words have lives, like RPG avatars, and they can get resurrected in new environments, if they have the right properties. And [Greek roots](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/wow/scans/Wow-6.pdf) are always available, just like [Latin](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/wow/scans/Wow-7.pdf), only more impressive.

Comment: @Zibbobz: I don't want to sound dismissive, since *you* obviously think the background to the word is interesting. But to me the most interesting thing about the question is that John Lawler's reference to building new words like assembling Lego kits gave me a chance to make a lame Leg6 pun that might appeal to our [Logophile/Legophile moderator](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/168/regdwight) if he chances upon it. In short, *xenomorph* is such an unexceptional "coinage" I really don't care who used it first in your exact sense (which others would simply "re-coin", rather than "copy").

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @JohnLawler, *Xenomorph* breaks down into Greek *xenos* (or, prefix *xen-* + [vowel]) meaning *strange[r] or foreign[er]*, and *morph* meaning *shape or form*.

Outside of the movie, *xenomorph* can be used in a few scientific contexts:

- *Xenomorphic* minerals have no intrinsic crystalline structure of their own, but have a structure impressed on them by surrounding structures or conditions.
- *Xenomorpha* is a synonym of *tardigrada*, a phylum of extremophiles.

Comment: Does *xenomorpha* for waterbears definitely predate the movie?

Comment: I didn't have time to find the full etymology, but I did find an [example from 1869](http://books.google.com/books?id=YWtTAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA350&lpg=PA350&dq=xenomorpha+etymology&source=bl&ots=uswmg2ui_l&sig=dmbTSWKHvJ1hwEPHXH9IShJRs-I&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UaOIU7ONILe-sQTHgYLACg&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=xenomorpha%20etymology&f=false), which I am *fairly* certain predates the movie, but I am not a film buff so don't quote me on that.

Comment: Well, even the John Carter film only took 80 years to finally get made, so I think you might be comfortably ahead of it there :)